# Regular Expression to find <>

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
"Absolutely<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64> Friendship goals exceeded here!! Sydney, Melbourne, Connecticut &amp; South Carolina<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>\r\n"
```

I want to separate only the <> part from the string. I tried `<.*>` but it returned

```
<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64> Friendship goals exceeded here!! Sydney, Melbourne, Connecticut &amp; South Carolina<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>
```

I dont want the words between them. I want the output as,

```
 ["<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64>", "<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>"]
```

Any help. I'm stuck in python.

Comment: `.*` is greedy add a `?` for the first occurrence. e.g. `<.*?>`.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. `.*?` isn't enough.

Comment: @EricDuminil Retracted.

Comment: @EricDuminil Why is it not a dup? `<.*?>` would `separate only the <> part from the string`. Capture it and group 1 would have it.

Comment: @chris85: Look at the desired output. OP wants 2 strings, not 24.

Comment: It's too simple `(?:<[^>]*>)+`

Comment: @EricDuminil aha, guess i had to scroll slower through that full block. A written description would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This pattern matches until it finds the first `>` not followed by a `<` :

```
import re

text = "Absolutely<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64> Friendship goals exceeded here!! Sydney, Melbourne, Connecticut &amp; South Carolina<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>\r\n"

pattern = "<.*?>(?!<)"

print re.findall(pattern, text)
#['<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64>', '<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like magic. Any explanation on pattern would be helpful.

Comment: Updated with link to doc and a short explanation. Do you understand it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<.*?>(?!<)` instead of `<.*>` .

This is what you may do

```
s = "Absolutely<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E64> Friendship goals exceeded here!! Sydney, Melbourne, Connecticut &amp; South Carolina<U+653C><U+3E64><U+613C><U+3E30><U+623C><U+3E64><U+653C><U+3E64><U+623C><U+3E31><U+383C><U+3E61>\r\n"

result = re.findall('<.*?>(?!<)',s)
```

Comment: He wants two items though.

Comment: Thanks! but it returns a concatenated string of two parts. I need to separate them as two different one.